# Why green light is good for our health?

Tags: human-biology, vision, eyes

I have a knowledge that when you woke up and see green light it increases your sight power. How it does so?

Comment: Any more specifics or evidence for that claim?

Comment: http://applications.nam.lighting.philips.com/blog/index.php/2015/08/06/the-subconscious-effect-of-colored-lighting/

Comment: There's nothing in there about green light increasing sight power, or about green light and waking. It reduces glare and provides good contrast for red objects, but it doesn't make your eyes any more powerful.